# How to disable auto collapse in mobile menu?

Tags: magento2, javascript, magento-2.1, jquery, menu

In mobile menu of Magento 2 when we click any child item of a parent, the parent collapse [see the image]

what can i do to disable this behaviour.

> Demo: http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/contact

[image]